# I can not properly update my progressbar

Tags: python, tkinter, progress-bar

I'm trying to update my progressbar when a button is clicked and the function should update when commanded(submit button clicked) but this does not happen properly

```
def progress(*args): #progressbar is set to be 50% completed
    p.step(50)
def submitted(*args): #Progressbar is set to be fully completed and states information recorded
    p.step(100)
    messagebox.showinfo("Information Submitted", "Your information has been recorded.")

def clear(*args): #Clears everything and returns gui to start of program
    l.selection_clear(0, END)
    t.delete('1.0', END)
    p.step(0)   

#Sets title and creates gui
root=Tk()

#Configures column and row settings and sets padding
mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

#Creates list of countries alphabetically
countries=["Finland", "France", "Greece", "Iceland", "Spain"]

l=Listbox(mainframe, height=5)
l.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S))


#Adds items in list to listbox
for i in countries:
    l.insert('end', i)


#Creates progessbar widget
p=ttk.Progressbar(mainframe, orient=VERTICAL, length=200, mode='determinate')
p.grid(column=2, row=0, sticky=(N,S))

#Activates progress function if something in listbox is selected
l.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', progress)

#Submitting calls submitted function to set progressbar to 100 and statemessage box has been completed
subbttn= ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Submit", command=submitted)
subbttn.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=(S, W, E))

clearbttn= ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Clear", command=clear)
clearbttn.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=(N, W, E))
#Clears all inputs and returns program to how it was in the beginning

#Runs loop for gui
root.mainloop()
```

After something in the listbox is clicked, the progressbar updates to 50% and that's good. However after clicking the submit button there is no change. Also if I change it to p.set(99) the progressbar seems to decrease in progress. I want the progressbar to be completely filled after clicking the submit button. Also after clciking the clear button, I want the progress bar to be at 0 and there is no change to the progressbar.

Comment: This is a lot of code.  Could you pare it down to just the essentials?

Comment: Well originally I thought I had already cut it down a lot and was pretty sure it was relevant, but I edited it just now and cut it down some more to the part where I think the problem is occurring.

Comment: It needs to be both minimal _and_ complete. Don't show code you _think_ has the problem, we need to see code that actually causes the problem. See http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I've kept it as minimal as possible with all possible related parts of problem included and the code is functioning so easy to run and understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p.step(100)` adds 100 and gets `"result modulo maximum"`
so you have `"0+100 modulo 100"` which gives 0.

But you can use `p["value"] = 100`

---

Button `Clear` doesn't change progressbar because there is unknown variable `t` in function `clear()` so you get error message before it can execute `p.step(0)`.

But `p.step(0)` doesn't set value to `0` - it adds `0` to current value.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like

```
p=ttk.Progressbar(mainframe, orient=VERTICAL, length=200, mode='determinate')
```

Becomes

```
p=ttk.Progressbar(mainframe, variable=progressvar,orient=VERTICAL, length=200, mode='determinate')
```

and

```
p.step(50)
```

becomes

```
progressvar.set(50)
```

Using a variable and attaching it to progressbar which you can set the value of will make everything work the way I want to. Any value change is perfectly completed.